# Not Equal Operation in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, compare, successor-arithmetics

I am trying to compare two **peano's number** in **prolog** , but some resualt is wrong .

Anyone can help me , this is my code :

```
%Not Equal
notequal(0,s(A),X).
notequal(s(A),0,X).
notequal(s(A),s(B),C):- A/=B .
```

OR

```
%Not Equal
notequal(0,s(A),X).
notequal(s(A),0,X).
notequal(s(A),s(B),C):- minus(A,s(0),S1),minus(B,s(0),S2),notequal(S1,S2,C) .
```

The output :

```
?- notequal(s(0),s(s(0)),S).
false.

?- notequal(s(0),0,S).
true .

?- notequal(0,s(0),S).
true.
```

**First output wrong**

Thank you .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need three arguments for such a predicate, after all you want to describe a relation between two numbers. And your last rule should call the predicate itself again:

```
notequal(0,s(_)).
notequal(s(_),0).
notequal(s(A),s(B)) :-  % s(A) and s(B) are not equal if
   notequal(A,B).       % A and B are not equal
```

This yields your desired answers:

```
?- notequal(0,0).
false.

?- notequal(0,s(0)).
true.

?- notequal(s(0),s(0)).
false.

?- notequal(s(s(0)),s(0)).
true ;
false.

?- notequal(s(s(0)),0).
true ;
false.
```

You can also use this with only one argument instantiated:

```
?- notequal(s(0),B).
B = 0 ;
B = s(s(_G2450)).

?- notequal(A,s(0)).
A = 0 ;
A = s(s(_G2450)).
```

As you can see all possibilities are covered with these two answers. Even the most general query is producing solutions:

```
?- notequal(A,B).
A = 0,
B = s(_G2456) ;
A = s(_G2456),
B = 0 ;
A = s(0),
B = s(s(_G2460)) ;
A = s(s(_G2460)),
B = s(0) ;
A = s(s(0)),
B = s(s(s(_G2464))) ;
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not need to find out the actual order of two numbers—say, for comparison-based sorting—but only need to state safe term disequality, use the widely-available built-in predicate `dif/2`!

Some sample queries:

```
?- dif(0, 0).
false.

?- dif(0, s(0)).
true.

?- dif(s(0), s(0)).
false.

?- dif(s(s(0)), s(0)).
true.

?- dif(s(s(0)), 0).
true.
```

This also works *safely* in the most general case:

```
?- dif(A, B).
dif(A, B).             % residual goal indicates pending disequality constraint
```